# Single Basin Disposal Plumbing

Tags: plumbing, pipe, kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal

I added a new deep basin sink recently and didn't think it thru enough. Due to the new depth, the disposal outlet will sit 6.5" below the bottom of the sink (to the middle of the outlet pipe). However the existing run of horizontal drain pipe heading into the wall is sitting at about 8 inches below the sink. (to center of the 2.5" pipe).

I did verify that the existing run of horizontal pipe is sloped to gravity drain appropriately. And I also can see that inside the wall the pipe runs horizontally (into more wall hidden by cabinets) instead of downward which means lowing the wall drain would be out of the question for me.

So my margins are tight on the disposal connection but are they sufficient? If not I will probably just ditch the disposal, but wanted to double check first.

Comment: This does not add up. You say the disposal is 2 inches **higher** than the drain, but you say lowering the drain is out of the question. Perhaps there's a typo here you want to [edit] to correct?

Comment: What I meant by that was that *if* I needed to lower the drain pipe, it would not be easily doable (and I probably would not attempt it) -- because inside the wall its not a vertical pipe that I could just cut off and move the tee lower, its a horizontal run behind cabinets.

To be clear, the drain *is* lower than the outlet of the disposal at the dimensions I gave, but I wasn't sure if there was any specific rule for how much lower it must be (to avoid having sitting water in the disposal, etc) - or if it *just* needs to be lower.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have water sitting in the garbage disposal all the time, but if the bottom of the pipe is lower then the bottom of the disposal output, that shouldn't happen. Personally, I would want the bottom of the horizontal part of the disposal to be higher than the top of the drain pipe (post trap), but as long as the drain is lower it should work.